# how to write a query in the error section using node js

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am doing bulk upload to mysql db using node js.I am inserting multiple rows and if any error happens in execution I have to update a column in a table.How can I do that.

```
var connection = createmysqlconnection(); 
var query1 = "INSERT INTO abc ("1","2");";
var query2 = "INSERT INTO xyz("3","4");";
var query3 = "INSERT INTO aaa("5","6");";
var sql = query1+query2+query3; 
connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) { 
    if (error) { 
        console.log("Error occured"); 
        connection.destroy(); 
        throw error; 
    } else { 
        // connected! 
        console.log(results); 
        callback(error, results); connection.end(); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far

Comment: var connection = createmysqlconnection();
    
     var query1 = "INSERT INTO abc ("1","2");
     var query2 = "INSERT INTO xyz("3","4");
     var query3 = "INSERT INTO aaa("5","6");
  var sql = query1+query2+query3;
  
  connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error occured");
            connection.destroy();
           throw error;
        } else {
            // connected!
               console.log(results);
           callback(error, results);
            connection.end();
        }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment, your queries are not correct, check the modifications required;

```
// make multiple statements true
var connection = mysql.createConnection({multipleStatements: true});

var query1 = "INSERT INTO abc VALUES("1","2");"; <== VALUES & `;` were missing
var query2 = "INSERT INTO xyz VALUES("3","4");";
var query3 = "INSERT INTO aaa VALUES("5","6");";
var sql = query1+query2+query3; 
connection.query(sql, function (error, results, fields) { 
    if (error) { 
        console.log("Error occured"); 
        connection.destroy(); 
        throw error; 
    } else { 
        // connected! 
        console.log(results); 
        callback(error, results); connection.end(); 
    } 
});
```

**Edit 1:** you can use following query to `INSERT OR UPDATE` in case of `DUPLICATE KEY`

```
var query1 = "INSERT INTO abc VALUES("1","2") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val1="1", val2=2;";
```

Comment: Yes.That was a mistake while I typed the queries.In my real code its correct.But can any one tell how can I do an UPDATE statement if any of the queries fail.

Comment: @DeepthiRajeev do you want to update row if it's having same primary key. that means DUPLICATE key violation error?

Comment: @DeepthiRajeev updated the answer if it's related to KEY VIOLATION

Comment: Actually I want to update the status column in a different table if the execution failed for any reason.I thought of doing it inside the if(error) block.But I am not able to execeute UPDATE statements inside the if condition.

Comment: Any pointers please..Basically my doubt is how can I execute an UPDATE statement inside the error block.